# Check if the values are the same (case insensitive )

Tags: javascript, regex, loops

I am trying to check if object values are the same and if so return true. For example, if all Fridays are 'ok' return true. If not return false.

I've tried using something like this but its not working...

```js
let schedule = {
  "paul": {
    "Friday": "ok",
    "Saturday": "OK",
    "Sunday": "--"
  },
  "peter": {
    "Friday": "Ok",
    "Saturday": "oK",
    "Sunday": "ok"
  },
  "mary": {
    "Friday": "ok",
    "Saturday": "OK",
    "Sunday": "--"
  }
}

const re = /ok/i

if (Object.values(schedule).every(obj => re.test(obj.Friday))) {
  console.log('match 05')
} else if (Object.values(schedule).every(obj => re.test(obj.Saturday))) {
  console.log('match 06')
} else if (Object.values(schedule).every(obj => re.test(obj.Sunday))) {
  console.log('match 07')
}
```

Comment: It works, just run `if`s separately, without `else`

Comment: what is the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the exact match then you can do that without using the regex. Also you should not combine the condition with `else if`, simply use `if` individually.

You can try the following way:

```js
var schedule = {
 "paul":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"OK","Sunday":"--"},
 "peter":{"Friday":"Ok","Saturday":"oK","Sunday":"ok"},
 "mary":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"OK","Sunday":"--"}
}

const s = 'ok';
const Friday = Object.values(schedule).every(obj => s == obj.Friday.toLowerCase());
const Saturday = Object.values(schedule).every(obj => s == obj.Friday.toLowerCase());
const Sunday = Object.values(schedule).every(obj => s == obj.Sunday.toLowerCase());
if(Friday) {
  console.log('match 05')
} 
if(Saturday) {
  console.log('match 06')
} 
if(Sunday) {
  console.log('match 07')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if`/`else` structure stops processing if the first check is true.

Try the following (removing the elses).

```js
const schedule = {
 "paul":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"OK","Sunday":"--"},
 "peter":{"Friday":"Ok","Saturday":"oK","Sunday":"ok"},
 "mary":{"Friday":"ok","Saturday":"OK","Sunday":"--"}
}

const re = /ok/i

if (Object.values(schedule).every(obj => re.test(obj.Friday))) {
  console.log('match 05')
}
if (Object.values(schedule).every(obj => re.test(obj.Saturday))) {
  console.log('match 06')
}
if (Object.values(schedule).every(obj => re.test(obj.Sunday))) {
  console.log('match 07')
}
```